# Safe Textinput text to array on space and clear Input

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello you magnificient people,

I am working on a tag system in react native. Text is written in a TextInput field and on space I would like to save the text as a tag in a state array and delete the text from the TextInput. Preferably I would like to include a autocomplete feature. How is this done?

I have looked into onKeyPress, but cannot figure it out, nor with checking on space

Thanks a lot for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this package for React Native https://github.com/peterp/react-native-tags it should solve your problem, and it is easy to implement

Comment: Thanks, completely overlooked it!

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of libraries to help with a few use cases. If it's minor we can build our own logic but if you want many things cover you can go with the libraries and later contribute to them.

One such library for your use case is this: https://github.com/prakhar1989/react-tags#readme

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer first of all, but unfortunately, this is a different framework. Im looking for something for react-native not react, there is no up to date library for react-native

Comment: M so sorry I misread react-native, have you tried the following one: https://github.com/peterp/react-native-tags. This seems to be fairly updated and maintained.

Comment: Thanks, completlety overlooked it, tried a different one that didnt work anymore :)